# SQL ELSE take whatever the current value is

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Could you help me write the ELSE statement when nothing fits the above conditions? I just want it take whatever the current value is.

```
CASE
WHEN (Country IS NULL AND (NAME like '%+US+%' OR NAME like '%US-%')) THEN "US"  
WHEN (Country IS NULL AND (NAME like '%+CA+%' OR NAME like '%CA-%')) THEN "CA"  
ELSE **take whatever it is in the Country column**
END AS Country,
```

Comment: Simply `ELSE Country`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For “whatever there is" part please try

ELSE COUNTRY

Comment: To make this answer more useful to readers of this question, consider adding a description to explain what you're doing and why you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ELSE COUNTRY` instead of `ELSE **take whatever it is in the Country column** END AS Country,`